# Exception caught in RequestBodyHandler

Tags: scala, amazon-s3, netty, nio

below is the code when user uploads a video from mobile application to S3

```
def uploadVideo = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request =>
      try {
        var height = 0
        var width = 0
        request.body.files.map { mov =>
          var videoName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mpeg"
          amazonS3Client.putObject(bucketVideos, videoName, mov.ref.file)
        }
        val map = Map("result" -> "success")
        Ok(write(map))
      } catch {
        case e: Exception =>
          Ok(write(Map("result" -> "error")))
      }
  }
```

the above code work fine but in case user cancel while uploading of video then error occurs

```
    [error] play - Exception caught in RequestBodyHandler
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuffer(AbstractNioWorker.java:434) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.writeFromUserCode(AbstractNioWorker.java:129) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:99) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:725) ~[netty.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.doEncode(OneToOneEncoder.java:71) ~[netty.jar:na]
```

and this doesn't go to catch block!!

> 1.can this is harmfull to server or not?(because it is not needed any response if error occours)
>
> 2.if yes, how to handle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all happening in Play's internals that are handling parsing the body of the `Request`. In fact, during the upload to your server, you haven't even *reached* the `try` block yet because the file hasn't finished uploading. Only once the upload is *complete* do you have the `TemporaryFile` available.

So no, you can't catch this error, and why would you want to? The user closed the connection. They're not even waiting for a response, so why send one? Let Play handle it.

This is also not a good way of handling an upload, though. For small files, it's passable, but if someone is proxying a huge video upload through your server to S3, it's going to:

1. Take almost twice is long to serve the response (which will cause the user to hang while you upload to S3).
2. **Block** one of Play's threads for handling requests for the entire time that file is uploading to S3, and given enough of these uploads (not many at all), you will no longer be able to process requests until an upload has completed.

Consider at least creating a separate [ExecutionContext](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.0/ThreadPools) to use for handling uploads, or even better, look into having the user upload directly to S3 via a signed form, which would remove the need to proxy the upload at all.

Comment: i post the simmilar question for review, please review it
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55544/uploading-a-video-using-future-in-s3